# Amcharts How to pass data to dataprovider

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to pass data to `dataProvider` in `Amcharts`. since my goal is differing the data according to user's input. I tried to apply concept used in this example 
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e22f40f4db023433b142f0a01d165adb

like code down below but cant troubleshoot why it doesn't work..

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="chartdivLine"></div>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>


<!-- Chart code -->
<script>

ii =250000;
mc= 2000;
years =1;

var aaR=0.05;
var aR =0.045;

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivLine", {

    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "ignoreAxisWidth":true,
        "title": "Market Value",

     }],

    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "title": "Above Average",
        "valueField": "value1"

     },

     {
        "id": "g2",
        "title": "Average",
        "valueField": "value2"
     }

    ],
    "dataProvider": getData(),  // Stuck here
    "categoryField": "date",
    });

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}

function getData(){

var chartData =[];
chartData.push( {
      "date":"2019-01-01",
        "value1":5,
        "value2":10

    });
chartData.push( {
    "date":"2020-01-01",
        "value1":12,
        "value2":11

    });
chartData.push( {
    "date":"2021-01-01",
        "value":19,
        "value2":25

    } );

 return chartData;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the type of chart in your makeChart config object (see https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#methods)

```
"type": "serial",
```

My adjustments are below, it runs in my pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzjxOb

```js
var ii = 250000;
var mc = 2000;
var years = 1;

var aaR = 0.05;
var aR = 0.045;

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivLine", {
  "type": "serial",
 "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
 "valueAxes": [{
  "id": "v1",
  "axisAlpha": 0,
  "position": "left",
  "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
  "title": "Market Value",

 }],

 "graphs": [{
  "id": "g1",
  "title": "Above Average",
  "valueField": "value1"

 },

 {
  "id": "g2",
  "title": "Average",
  "valueField": "value2"
 }

 ],
 "dataProvider": getData(),  // :)
 "categoryField": "date",
});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
 chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}

function getData() {

 var chartData = [];
 chartData.push({
  "date": "2019-01-01",
  "value1": 5,
  "value2": 10

 });
 chartData.push({
  "date": "2020-01-01",
  "value1": 12,
  "value2": 11

 });
 chartData.push({
  "date": "2021-01-01",
  "value1": 19,
  "value2": 25

 });

 return chartData;
}
```

Comment: I got rid of that part to make it focused on the issue i'm asking. But thanks I've figured it out